# best way to handle multiple options scala

Tags: scala, monads, option-type

I currently am working with some scala code that has multiple Option types, that I need to set on an object (if they exist

currently I am doing the following

```
def myFunc(arg1: Option[Int], arg2: Option[Float]) {
    val objSet1 = arg1.fold(obj)(obj.setArg1)
    val objSet2 = arg2.fold(objSet1)(objSet1.setArg2)
    obj.runComputation()
}
```

I feel like there's a way to do this more elegantly with a for comprehension, but my monad thinking is failing me on how...

Comment: Where is `obj` defined? What is its type? Why are your input parameters (`arg1` and `arg2`) not used anywhere in that function?

Comment: @Snark need more information about what you want to do with these options. also need to know what happens when arg1 is none or arg2 is none

Comment: this intgrates a library so I literally collect arguments and wrap an underlying function call.

Comment: Oh, whoops, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's actually anything built in, but you can do this:

```
implicit class MaybeModifyOps [T](underlying: T) {
  def maybeModify[X](a: Option[X])(f: (T,X) => T): T = a.fold(underlying)(f(underlying,_))
}
```

and use it like this:

```
obj
  .maybeModify(arg1)(_ setArg1 _)
  .maybeModify(arg2)(_ setArg2 _)
  .runComputation()
```